# force view to be updated from within a valueconverter

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Somebody posted this yesterday on gitter. I ws running into the same issue lately. since this is a common usecase i just post his question here again so it doen't get lost in the gitter universe... 
Is there a simple way to force a ValueConverter to always call toView for every fromView? I have an  that I'm using a ValueConverter with to clamp to integers only. It works, but with a strange twist: If I change it from 0 to 1.5 and click away (also using updateTrigger:'blur' here), it correctly stores 1 in the VM and then changes the input value to 1 as well. But if I change it from 1 to 1.5, it updates the VM, but since the value in the VM doesn't appear to change, it doesn't update the input (no call to toView).
I know I could solve this with an event listener and signal, but that feels like overkill.
thanks

Comment: looks like there is already an issue for that:
https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/353

Comment: it's solved but there is room for improvement thats why i've created an issue for this:
https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/446

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better to use a binding behavior if you want to add "behavior".  This will give you more control, you could even control the cursor, etc.

https://gist.run?id=3d2870889cbf245e652f53db28d8476b

**integer-input-binding-behavior.js**

```js
export class IntegerInputBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, source) {
    binding.standardUpdateSource = binding.updateSource;
    binding.updateSource = function(value) {
      const intValue = parseInt(value, 10);
      if (isNaN(intValue)) {
        this.standardUpdateSource(0);
        return;
      }
      this.standardUpdateSource(intValue);
      if (intValue.toString(10) !== value) {
        this.updateTarget(intValue.toString(10));
      }
    };
  }

  unbind(binding, source) {
    binding.updateSource = binding.standardUpdateSource
    binding.standardUpdateSource = null;
  }
}
```

Better still to create a custom element.

Comment: hi jeremy, thanks for this answer. i see bindingbehaviours are much more powerful than valueconverters. but i'm a bit puzzled now for what valueconverters are good for in the end? imagine having to convert date entries to js date objects. well this sounds like a perfect canfidate for value converters as well bit it will fail for the same reason... so maybe i should just ask, what are valueconverters good for?

Comment: hmm after reading my comment i feel stupid :) i know that they pretty much do what their name implies but a simple possibility to force a view update from within the vc would be really nice...

Comment: Just like value converters in xaml- stateless, no behavior.  Most commonly used for display formatting.  Not for creating controls, at least not on their own.

Comment: i see the value of the valueconverters ;) when it comes to displaying and formatting values. but the fromView() allows ViewModel modification and can cause the view and viewmodel to be out of sync.
just 2 more scenarios where this will happen:
- vm saves float with 2 digit precision, v allows entries like 2.456 (more than  2 precision)
- a date entry which allows you to enter: 3.6 which gets then automatically converted to 03.06.2016. optionally the user can enter only 3 and it will also be translated to the same date thus the view still shows just 3 instead of 03.06.2016 in this case

Comment: I think this line `binding.standardSource = binding.standardUpdateSource;` should be -> `binding.updateSource = binding.standardUpdateSource;`

Answer (score 0):

### **Use the `signal` binding behavior**

You'll see in the issue you linked that I had commented with a similar question. The solution I implemented was to use the `signal` binding behavior.

**template.html**

```
<path d="${path| toSVGPath & signal: 'update-view'}" 
      style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 5; fill: none;"></path>
```

**viewModel.ts**

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-binding';

// grab a reference to the signaler
constructor(signaler: BindingSignaler) {
    this.path = [[0,0]];
    this.signaler = signaler;
}

// and fire the signal event bound in your view
// whenever the data behind the valueConverter changes
updatePath(position) {
    this.path.push(position);
    this.signaler.signal('update-view');
}
```

Comment: thanks for this proposal, but somehow ghis should be simpler :) see my comment above in jeremys answer. there are more and more use cases popping up in my mind which would require a simple view update after conversion.

Comment: but i really like the signal behaviour, i'm even thinking on somehow disable the aurelia update view magic (which i still didn't grasp 100%) and solely rely on signaler and explicitly signal the changes everywhere in my code

Comment: how could this be simpler...?

Comment: i'm not refering to your code (thanks btw.) which looks good to me i'm refering to the fact that we have to use a signaler in combination with the valueconverter to solve such a use case with aurelia out of the box components.

Comment: while I agree with you, I think its a mostly nice solution given the constraints, particularly that we're using plain javascript properties, and not knockout-style pub/sub properties.